# How to catch a raised event in a DLL in PowerBuidler

Tags: c#, events, dll, powerbuilder

Is there a way to catch an event raised in COM visble DLL made in c# in PowerBuilder? I use OLEObject to instantiate the DLL in PowerBuilder App and am able to call the functions, But how can I catch an event raised in the DLL?

Answer (score 0):

The C# OLEobject needs to be added to the form (via the 'add OLE object' - Insert Object dialogue window).  This will make the events exposed via com visible in Powerscript (assuming the object has events coded).

Answer (score 0):

What Matt said would probably work for dropped in OLEObjects but I haven't had luck preventing PB crashes when referencing non-existent 'object' properties of an OLEObject without using the **catch** of try, catch, finally block.

**Try... Catch... Finally... Block**

If you read the documentation for PB for Try, Catch, Finally you'll see that you can "Catch" many different error types and **OLEError** is one of them. There is a generic error and than specialized error types that allow you to handle different scenarios. This is great for OLEErrors, or referencing object (any) type properties of an OLEObject that don't exist which would normally crash PB. Using the correct error object and catch, you can prevent PB from crashing even if an OLE property that doesn't exist is referenced.

This is the preferred method of error handling in later versions of PB as you can add catches (and handling) for anything from system errors, ole errors, and many more for which I cannot remember offhand but they should be listed in PB help - keep digging PB didn't do a good job of making the help entry easy to find.

If you can't find them in PB help look in the **Object Browser** for **error object types**. Once you start using this feature your PB programs will be much more solid and your end-users will be happy.